# Getting "Cannot evaluate a security function" when using conditional breakpoints and in immediate window

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

When developing .NET Core 2.0 applications, I'm having issues with conditional breakpoints, watch evaluations, and immediate window evaluations. I'm receiving the following error:

> `modifiers.GroupBy(c => c.Modifier.Group).ToList()`
>  
>          threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'
>           Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
>           HResult: -2147024809
>           HelpLink: null
>           InnerException: null
>           Message: "Cannot evaluate a security function."
>           ParamName: null
>           Source: null
>           StackTrace: null
>           TargetSite: null

What may cause this issue? Is there a workaround? This works just fine in a .NET Framework 4.x application.

---

**Edit:** Adding code sample

Using the following class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
}
```

In a normal console application, targeting .NET Core 2.0:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var people = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person { Age = 17, Name = "Person A", Group = "Group A" },
        new Person { Age = 20, Name = "Person B", Group = "Group A" },
        new Person { Age = 23, Name = "Person C", Group = "Group A" },
        new Person { Age = 17, Name = "Person D", Group = "Group B" },
        new Person { Age = 25, Name = "Person E", Group = "Group B" },
        new Person { Age = 40, Name = "Person F", Group = "Group B" },
    };
    // Make sure that System.Linq gets loaded
    people.Where(c => c.Name == "Person A").First();
}
```

Set a breakpoint after the initialization of the `List<Person>`. In the **immediate window**, trying to evaluate a `GroupBy` or a `Where` which is not a simple equality check, it will throw an `ArgumentException` with the message "Cannot evaluate a security function."

A couple of examples would be:

```
people.Where(c => c.Name.Contains("F")).ToList()

people.GroupBy(c => c.Group).ToList()
```

**Note:** The watch statements seems to be working in Visual Studio Code, but not in Visual Studio 2017 Preview 3.

Comment: Do you have a sample code to allow reproducing that problem?

Comment: Sample code and some notes has been added. Thanks!

Comment: At which line is the exception thrown?

Comment: @Fabulous The exception is thrown in the watch and immediate window. Two examples stated in the post.

Comment: You could try toggling the `Use legacy C# and VB expression evaluators` in `Debug -> Options`

Comment: I am not sure why you're suggesting that... The legacy expression evaluator doesn't support Lambda, remember?

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with VS2017.3. I've tested this with v15.2 and I don't get any errors. Have you tried with Core 1.1?

Comment: Got the same issue with 2017.3, going to update to 2017.3.1 to see if it still persists.

Comment: Same here, I reported error on VS Community. I cannot evaluate any functions into debugger, just variables, it's annoying ...

Comment: @cdie can you share the link to your report so we can upvote?

Comment: @zaitsman yep, right here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/104113/debugger-cannot-evaluate-security-function.html

Answer (score 9):

That error seems to be due to the immediate window disallowing anything that *may* cause side-effects.  Usually side-effects are allowed in the immediate window... but it does not like `GroupBy` on `List<T>` (while `GroupBy` on `T[]` is tolerated)

I reproduced using your example.

`people.GroupBy(c => c.Group).ToList()` throws
`people.Where(c => c.Name.Contains("F")).ToList()` does not.

It did *not* require a conditional breakpoint.  My test was with a brand new .net core 2.0 project Debug Any CPU build. This was the stable release of VS Pro 2017 v15.3.1

To get around this issue, make a copy of your list into an array:

`people.ToArray().GroupBy(c => c.Group).ToList()`

I also recommend filing a bug report with MS.

Comment: It works in .NET Framework 4.6 but not in .NET Core. I'm afraid I am not confident you're correct.

Comment: @AndreAndersen perhaps I misunderstood.  Let me restate what I think is happening.  In .NET Framework 4.6, as you mention, you are able to use the immediate window without issues.  In a .NET Core 2.0 project, you run into the 'Cannot evaluate ...' error when you type `people.GroupBy(c => c.Group).ToList()` but if you instead type `people.ToArray().GroupBy(c => c.Group).ToList()` it does not throw.  Is this correct?

Comment: Ok great.  So now I'm puzzled regarding why you would not be confident that `List<T>.GroupBy()` vs `T[].GroupBy()` being the cause of the "potential side effect" (which is the cause of the security error) only in `.NET Core 2.0` not in `.NET Framework 4.6`?  My assumption is some metadata differs between the two implementations of `List<T>` in such a way that the IDE halts the evaluation because it believes it might mutate data (even though data mutation is generally allowed in the Immediate window) -- possibly because of optimizations or stack modifications